# PHP: Post to self

Tags: php, post, web

I want to write a php page that basically takes an array, $_POST['selection'],
lets a user select one of the keys to delete, and refresh itself with the shorter array.

I saw:

```
echo '< form method="POST" action="Results.php?selection='.urlencode($myArray).'">;
echo '<input type='submit'></form>';
```

Would this work?

If not, how should I go about this?

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: How did you set the post value. Have you looked at json?

Answer (score 0):

It would not work, `urlencode` [does not accept an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php),
it just return a string, `Array`

If $myArray is an associative array :-

```
urlencode(http_build_query($myArray));
```

Function [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) will glue the associate key and value like :-

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```

And the urlencode will encoded the string properly

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tailor this to suit your needs, but with such a general question there are tons of answers.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['selection'])) {
    $myArray = $_POST['selection']);
} else {
    $myArray = array(
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'more',
        'jazz',
    );
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <?php foreach ($myArray as $key => $value): ?>
        <label for="input<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></label>
        <input id="input<?php echo $key; ?>" type="checkbox" name="selection[]" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```